# displaying html in flash player

Tags: html, flash

Is there a way to render HTML pages within flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an answer: http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/

It seems to be an HTML renderer written in flash. Might be useful for IE6 users.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a Flash html renderer? I know this one : http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/

Answer (score 1):

See this: [Embedding HTML in a Flex application using an IFrame](http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm)

Answer (score -1):

Since you aren't specific

```
loadText = new LoadVars();
loadText.load("example.htm");
```

Will load the HTML text into flash (as a string)